# Firebase Auth - No Provider Data on Android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I've upgraded to the 9.0.2 SDK version following the [solved auth problem on Android devices](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/16001). My FirebaseUI-Android package version is 0.4.0 and my device's Google Play Services version is 9.0.83.

Following the fix, my app does authenticate, but alas it does not populate any provider data automatically (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXICG.png)), nor does it provide it when called via getProviderData().

When getProviderData().toString() is called, I get:
[com.google.android.gms.internal.zzadf@3a3aa0b, com.google.android.gms.internal.zzadf@a00f0e8]

It does give the provider itself when getProviders().toString() is called (e.g. "google.com").

Thanks,
Yohay

Answer (score 0):

You can browse `getProvidersData`, it contains `? extends UserInfo` objects where you can get `getProviderId()` from `UserInfo`.